# Editing large Python file consumes systems resources

Tags: python, editor

I'm creating a file with a list variable that contains 2,000 string entries.

Please note I'm not talking about when I run the code but just while I'm typing to create the file does my computer start to hog tons of memory. As soon as I delete all those words from line 6 is clears up.

I am editing in IDLE.
The list is here: http://pastebin.com/uwpKriZ3

**FYI**

Here is the abbreviated sample code:

```
import random

# The following line is unwrapped and, in the actual script,
# contains 26431 characters comprising 2000 words:
list1 = ['aback', 'abaft', 'abandoned', 'abashed', 'aberrant', 'abhorrent', 'abiding']

rndword = random.choice(list1)
brokenword = list(rndword)
```

Comment: Can we see the code please?

Comment: 2000 words isn't very long list ..... your problem must be other ....

Comment: This is my first time posting on stack exchange. I hope I'm doing this right.

http://pastebin.com/uwpKriZ3

Comment: So you're trying to select a random choice from a list of words, which is totally different from what you described in this question

Comment: What kind of computer do you use? Your script is [Finished in 0.1s] on my machine.

Comment: I edited this to ask the actual question -- waiting for edit to be approved

Comment: @matthias, it's not when I run it. It's just when i'm writing the code in a new file that my computer freezes

Comment: Your list works perfect... I'm keeping it in my collection of generated stuff

Comment: @clickhere What editor are you using? That is a big text file for an editor to work with sometimes.

Comment: Your text editor is deficient. Try using shorter lines, like this: http://pastebin.com/zqvizFSf

Comment: What text editor are you using? What type of machine?

Comment: It seems the editor he’s using is IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That variable assignment line is 26431 characters long—long enough to even make emacs run slowly. Try doing a find/replace to replace each comma with comma followed by a newline.

Most of the time when writing actual programs, if you need to load a lot of data, you could read in the data from a file. To do this in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import io

list1 = [line.strip() for line in io.open('data.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig")]

rndword = random.choice(list1)
brokenword = list(rndword)
print(brokenword)
```

Reading data from an external source recognizes that data and code are different things. It also encourages code reusability/generalization. For example, you may come up with a useful algorithm that could be applied to different datasets. Why put the dataset right into the source code when you could instead have a polished python script which you could feed different data without needing to modify it? Just keep the code and data separate and, suddenly, you have cleaner, more reusable code.

Comment: why not set the encoding when opening the file if `open()` statement and avoid the explicit decode? It'll also work nicer with UTF-8 BOMs.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Please edit that in, if you would! I know that I am not setting a good example on how to do I/O with python…

Comment: drop `readlines()` it is unnecessary here. Drop `list()` around `[]`.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: `open()` does not use BOM. It uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` by default. If you know that the file is utf-8; you should provide the character encoding explicitly.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes - That's exactly what I suggested! My point is that `io.open(encoding="utf-8")` ignores UTF8 BOMs on `read()`

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: I read (incorrectly) your first comment as a suggestion to remove `encoding='utf-8'` parameter i.e., leave only `io.open('data.txt')` that does not use BOM (I don't know of any utf-16 locale). `encoding='utf-8'` also does not use BOM (you need `'utf-8-sig'` for that). `utf-16` does use BOM.

Comment: Cool :) It's because the answer was updated to match my suggestion (see edits) :). As for BOMs, `utf-8` ignores/skips BOMs on read whereas `utf-8-sig` is used when you want one automatically writing - this I discovered a few days ago.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: to be clear: if file has `BOM_UTF8` then you want `utf-8-sig` to read the file otherwise BOM is left in the stream.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, sorry, you are correct. I assumed the BOM would appear as an unknown char or as an literal when printed. I just checked the `repr` and can see that it's there. Thanks for correction :)